# Scrapy Problem with Excel and Product Pictures

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

My problem is complete, I created a script for scraping an online hsop with Scrapy.  Unfortunately, not all of the urls I specified are written to the .csv file in the .csv file.  There are always some missing, like in the example below I only took 5 product pages but I only get 4 in the .csv file.

Image from the .csv file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odTku.png)

But I noticed when I run the code again, they all swap to:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RhGM.png)

My code is:

```
import scrapy
import csv
import os
import requests


class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "product_spider"

    start_urls = [
        'https://softwarekaufen24.de/microsoft-office-2021-home-and-student/',
        'https://softwarekaufen24.de/windows-11-pro/',
        'https://softwarekaufen24.de/windows-11-home/',
        'https://softwarekaufen24.de/windows-10-professional/',
        'https://softwarekaufen24.de/windows-10-home/'
    ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filename = 'product.csv'
        self.logo_dir = 'logos'
        if not os.path.exists(self.logo_dir):
            os.makedirs(self.logo_dir)
        with open(self.filename, mode='w', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
            writer.writerow(
                ['Product Title', 'Product Price', 'Old Product Price', 'Product Description', 'Breadcrumb', 'Product Link', 'Logo Path'])

    def parse(self, response):
        product_title = response.css('h1[class="product--title"]::text').get()
        if product_title:
            product_title = product_title.strip()

        product_price = response.css(
            'meta[itemprop="price"]::attr(content)').get()

        # Old Product Price auswählen
        old_product_price = response.css(
            'span.price--line-through::text').get()

        # Beschreibung auswählen
        product_description = response.css(
            'div.product--description:nth-child(2)').extract_first()
        if product_description:
            # Unerwünschten Text entfernen
            product_description = product_description.replace(
                "SOFTWARE KAUFEN LEICHT GEMACHT!", "").strip()
            product_description = product_description.replace(
                "\n", " ").replace("\r", "")

        # Breadcrumb auswählen
        breadcrumb_items = response.css(
            'span.breadcrumb--title[itemprop="name"]')
        breadcrumb = ''
        for item in breadcrumb_items:
            breadcrumb += item.css('::text').get() + ' > '
        breadcrumb = breadcrumb[:-3]

        # Produkt-Link auswählen
        product_link = response.url

# Logo herunterladen
        logo_path = ''
        supplier_div = response.css('div[class="product--supplier"]')
        if supplier_div:
            img_url = supplier_div.css('img::attr(src)').get()
            img_alt = supplier_div.css('img::attr(alt)').get()
            if img_url and img_alt:
                img_filename = img_alt.replace(
                    ' ', '_') + os.path.splitext(img_url)[1]
                logo_path = os.path.join(self.logo_dir, img_filename)
                if not os.path.exists(logo_path):
                    self.log(f'Downloading logo: {img_url}')
                    img_data = requests.get(img_url).content
                    with open(logo_path, 'wb') as img_file:
                        img_file.write(img_data)
                    # Check if the downloaded image is SVG format
                    if os.path.splitext(img_filename)[1].lower() == '.svg':
                        # Convert SVG to PNG using the inkscape command-line tool
                        subprocess.run(
                            ['inkscape', '--export-type=png', logo_path], check=True)

        with open(self.filename, mode='a', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
            writer.writerow(
                [product_title, product_price, old_product_price, product_description, breadcrumb, product_link, logo_path])

        self.log(
            f'Produktname "{product_title}", Preis "{product_price}", Alter Preis "{old_product_price}", Beschreibung "{product_description}", Breadcrumb "{breadcrumb}", Link "{product_link}", Firmenname "{company_name}" und Firmenlogo "{company_logo}" wurden erfolgreich in {self.filename} gespeichert.')
```

Who can tell me where the error is? I was on it all day but I couldn't solve the problem, why aren't all the products written to the .csv file the first time?

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain what specific issue is causing your problems but I have discovered a number of errors in your code.

1. You are calling `subprocess.run` without importing the `subprocess` module.
2. In the very last line of your code you are referencing two variables that don't exist.
3. `company_name` and `company_logo` are never defined anywhere is in your script.

By simply fixing the above noted issues might resolve your issue with the current results you are getting.

For example:

```
import scrapy
import csv
import os
import requests
import subprocess


class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "product_spider"

    start_urls = [
        'https://softwarekaufen24.de/microsoft-office-2021-home-and-student/',
        'https://softwarekaufen24.de/windows-11-pro/',
        'https://softwarekaufen24.de/windows-11-home/',
        'https://softwarekaufen24.de/windows-10-professional/',
        'https://softwarekaufen24.de/windows-10-home/'
    ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filename = 'product.csv'
        self.logo_dir = 'logos'
        if not os.path.exists(self.logo_dir):
            os.makedirs(self.logo_dir)
        with open(self.filename, mode='w', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
            writer.writerow(
                ['Product Title', 'Product Price', 'Old Product Price', 'Product Description', 'Breadcrumb', 'Product Link', 'Logo Path'])

    def parse(self, response):
        product_title = response.css('h1[class="product--title"]::text').get()
        if product_title:
            product_title = product_title.strip()

        product_price = response.css(
            'meta[itemprop="price"]::attr(content)').get()

        # Old Product Price auswählen
        old_product_price = response.css(
            'span.price--line-through::text').get()

        # Beschreibung auswählen
        product_description = response.css(
            'div.product--description:nth-child(2)').extract_first()
        if product_description:
            # Unerwünschten Text entfernen
            product_description = product_description.replace(
                "SOFTWARE KAUFEN LEICHT GEMACHT!", "").strip()
            product_description = product_description.replace(
                "\n", " ").replace("\r", "")

        # Breadcrumb auswählen
        breadcrumb_items = response.css(
            'span.breadcrumb--title[itemprop="name"]')
        breadcrumb = ''
        for item in breadcrumb_items:
            breadcrumb += item.css('::text').get() + ' > '
        breadcrumb = breadcrumb[:-3]

        # Produkt-Link auswählen
        product_link = response.url

# Logo herunterladen
        logo_path = ''
        supplier_div = response.css('div[class="product--supplier"]')
        if supplier_div:
            img_url = supplier_div.css('img::attr(src)').get()
            img_alt = supplier_div.css('img::attr(alt)').get()
            if img_url and img_alt:
                img_filename = img_alt.replace(
                    ' ', '_') + os.path.splitext(img_url)[1]
                logo_path = os.path.join(self.logo_dir, img_filename)
                if not os.path.exists(logo_path):
                    self.log(f'Downloading logo: {img_url}')
                    img_data = requests.get(img_url).content
                    with open(logo_path, 'wb') as img_file:
                        img_file.write(img_data)
                    # Check if the downloaded image is SVG format
                    if os.path.splitext(img_filename)[1].lower() == '.svg':
                        # Convert SVG to PNG using the inkscape command-line tool
                        subprocess.run(
                            ['inkscape', '--export-type=png', logo_path], check=True)

        with open(self.filename, mode='a', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
            writer.writerow(
                [product_title, product_price, old_product_price, product_description, breadcrumb, product_link, logo_path])

        self.log(
            f'Produktname "{product_title}", Preis "{product_price}", Alter Preis "{old_product_price}", Beschreibung "{product_description}", Breadcrumb "{breadcrumb}", Link "{product_link}", Firmenname "" und Firmenlogo "" wurden erfolgreich in {self.filename} gespeichert.')
```

Additionally, I recommend taking advantage of scrapy's built in feed exports and media pipeline features instead of creating and managing the csv file yourself and using the requests library to download the image information in a separate request.

By populating a few settings in your `settings.py` file or in the `custom_settings` field and/or using the `-o filename.csv` command line option you could eliminate roughly half of the code in your script:

I suggest reading the scrapy docs [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html?highlight=media%20pipeline#using-the-images-pipeline) and [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html?highlight=feed%20exports#feed-exports)  and [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#crawl) specifically the `-o` or `--output` command line arguments for the last link.